# How to get date time from screenshot exif data

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin, screenshot, exif

I would like to use the following code to get the screenshot capture datetime

```
val file = File(image)
val exif = ExifInterface(file.absolutePath)
var datetime1 = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME)
val datetime2 = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL)
val datetime3 = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED)
println ("datetime = $datetime1")
```

at onActivityResult, if selected image is a photo, it's work
[image]

but if image is a screenshot, it will return null
[image]

any solution?

Update

Answer by Nikola Despotoski

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes

val lastModDate = Date(file.lastModified())
println("File last modified @ : $lastModDate")


if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val path = Paths.get(file.absolutePath)
    var attr = Files.readAttributes(
        path,
        BasicFileAttributes::class.java
    )
    var creationTime = attr.creationTime()
    var lastAccessTime = attr.lastAccessTime()
    var lastModifiedTime = attr.lastModifiedTime()
    println("Creation time: $creationTime")
    println("Last access time: $lastAccessTime")
    println("Last modified time: $lastModifiedTime")
}
```

[image]

It's work~

Comment: The date time is in the file name. Use it as png files have no exif header. You could use file time too.

Comment: Thx a lot for idea, it's work~